# Axios get request for specific ID returning all IDs

Tags: reactjs, http, axios

I'm trying to run a get request for a specific ID in my componentDidMount function and instead of accessing only the id's values, it is returning every id and every value.  Here is my code.

```
state = {
    marketing: [],
  };

async componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(config.apiEndpoint, { params: { id: 1 } }).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.setState({ marketing: res.data });
    });
```

config.apiEndpoint is my API URL stored in another file.  I am trying to only access the values for the number 1 id but it is accessing all of the ids. The console.log shows every id instead of just id:1.

I followed the code from this website https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/Axios.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index and I don't understand what I am doing wrong.   Any help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You component is ever rendering. You can't do async on componentDidMount directly, is easier for your compile know that inside that componentDidMount lays a async function to fire side Effect than been a async function, another thing is that you putting setState inside of componentDidMount with makes your component fire side effects on every frame which may lead to perfomance lacks

```
 constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);

   state = {
       marketing: [],
     };
    }


public fetchData() { 
    async () => await axios.get(config.apiEndpoint, { params: { id: 1 } }).then((res) => {
      this.setState({marketing: res})
    });


componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData()               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with your React component. It is more likely to be either a problem in the API or that you are calling an incorrect method or with an incorrect payload.